# Why wont Python's SQLite3 Update

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

This worked earlier, some of my rows have valid entries, but a lot of them don't...

```
def setLength(vid, seconds):
    db_conn.execute("UPDATE Videos SET length= '" + str(seconds//1) + "' WHERE ID='"+str(vid)+"';")
    db_conn.commit()
    result = my_cursor.execute("SELECT length, title FROM Videos WHERE ID = " + "'" + str(vid) + "';")
    for row in result:
        print(vid, row[0])
    print("gets here")
```

gives the output:

```
gets here
```

even when I run it with a valid ID.

Edit: I can use the same ID to get the title column from that row, but trying to UPDATE the length column just leaves the cell empty.

Comment: Are any errors reported? What do you mean by 'some rows have valid entries, but others dont`. What makes them invalid?

Comment: I think that you're expecting the function to print a row inside your `for` loop, but it is not printing that row.  So, I think you have the same problem without the `db_conn` statements.  You don't have an update problem.  The record `ID` is not in the database behind `my_cursor`.

Comment: See edit. The ID is definitely in the database because I can use it to read the video title. Some videos have lengths for some reason, and others are just an empty string. I can’t make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Does it work if you use parameter substitution, as described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902408/5320906)?  Note that sqlite uses `?` as a placeholder, not `%s`.  For example `dbconn.execute("UPDATE Videos SET length= ? WHERE ID= ?", (seconds//1, vid))`  (and similar for the select)

Answer (score 0):

Probably extremely specific but the reason it wasn't updating was because when inserting into the table some of the IDs were converted to scientific notation. Those that were would have their titles found, because the function I used for the title search was sensitive to that. My bad.

| ID | Title | Filename | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.72986707541665e+ | untitled | 253c95c4b27116e.mp | None |
| 263857279641976794 | ShowIWanttoWatchEp | Videos/ShowIWantto | 1144.0 |
| 185690842836020994 | ShowIWanttoWatchEp | Videos/ShowIWantto | 1174.0 |
| 1.7317732968119e+6 | untitled | 9231941.m4v | None |
| 212666122173993805 | ShowIWanttoWatchEp | Videos/ShowIWantto | 995.0 |
| 1.69406306986304e+ | untitled | hls-1.mp4 | None |
| 877482402128334556 | ShowIWanttoWatchEp | Videos/ShowIWantto | 1214.0 |